# How to return blank if the resulting SUMIFS criteria contains blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simplified table as follows:

| row1 | A | A | B | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row2 | C | D | C | D |
| 01/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 02/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 03/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 04/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 05/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 06/06/2023 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 07/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 08/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 09/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 10/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 11/06/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I would like to create a sum of the values where the date is 06/06/2023 and the first row cells are equal to "A". If the resulting `SUMIFS` criteria contains a blank, I would like to return blank. So the result should be blank not 1 in this case.

Comment: And what return if date isn't 06/06/2023 ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Revised Answer

I think both @Dominique and I misunderstood this question at first. You want a sum **over all columns marked "A"** for any given date, as long as none of the included entries is blank. Column F gives you those sums for each date (note the blank in `F8`). Use a COUNTIFS() statement with the same criteria as the `SUMIFS`, and include blank (`"=" & ""`) as another criterion. If `COUNTIFS() > 0` leave the sum blank. (Note that the `SUMIFS()` could be simplified to `SUMIF()`, if you want to rewrite it.)

This works with the simplified data layout provided. Whether you can extend it to your needs depends on your actual data. In particular, if you have multiple rows with the same date, this will require further edits. Also, Excel 365 might provide a simpler method, but I don't have access to it.

Per @DavidLeal suggestion, the simple form is:

```
G3: =IF(COUNTIFS($B3:$E3, "", $B$1:$E$1, "A") <> 0, "", SUMIFS($B3:$E3, $B$1:$E$1, "A"))
```

I've kept the original to illustrate including the sign in case it's needed for an inequality (in a different context):

```
F3: =IF(COUNTIFS($B3:$E3, "=" & "", $B$1:$E$1, "A") <> 0, "", SUMIFS($B3:$E3, $B$1:$E$1, "A"))
```

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** | **F** | **G** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | row1 | A | A | B | B | Sum of A | Sum of B |
| **2** | row2 | C | D | C | D |  |  |
| **3** | 1/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **4** | 2/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **5** | 3/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **6** | 4/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **7** | 5/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **8** | 6/6/2023 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |
| **9** | 7/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **10** | 8/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **11** | 9/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **12** | 10/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| **13** | 11/6/2023 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

To extend this to columns labeled "B", put a similar formula in column G:

```
G3: =IF(COUNTIFS($B3:$E3, "=" & "", $B$1:$E$1, "B") <> 0, "", SUMIFS($B3:$E3, $B$1:$E$1, "B"))
```

To copy this across a number of column labels, this will work **if the entries in Row 1 are labelled as in the example** ("Sum of A", etc.):

```
F3: =IF(COUNTIFS($B3:$E3, "=" & "", $B$1:$E$1, RIGHT(F$1, 1)) <> 0, "", SUMIFS($B3:$E3, $B$1:$E$1, RIGHT(F$1, 1)))
```

Comment: Good solution, I guess it would be enough: `""` to check for blanks instead of `"=" & ""`

Comment: @DavidLeal Good catch. I started off trying `"<>" & ""`, where the not equal sign **is** required. Didn't even occur to me to eliminate the sign when I realized that equal was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your formula is correct?
I used the following one, and blank cells are counted as zero:

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B12,$A3:$A12,DATE(2023,6,6))
```

I have entered this into cell "B14" in my Excel sheet and dragged it to "C14", causing a zero result. In case you don't like a zero result, you can always replace it by a blank cell, using this simple `IF()`-formula (cell "B15", dragged to "C15"):

```
=IF(SUMIFS(B3:B12,$A3:$A12,DATE(2023,6,6))=0," ",SUMIFS(B3:B12,$A3:$A12,DATE(2023,6,6)))
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to sum B8 and C8 cells together, and I would like it to return blank in this case, as the range contains a blank. I would like to generalize it to other rows too, so it should return 2 for other rows.

Comment: @Nick: that shouldn't be too hard. Just do something like: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B8), ISBLANK(C8), ...)," ", SUMIFS(...))`.

Comment: Yes, the thing is that this is just a simplified table, the real table is bigger and I am using offset, index, match to pin down the range that I want to apply SUMIFS, and then in that range it's possible to have blank cells.

Comment: Using ```IF(SUMIFS(...) = 0...``` works if the only possible entries are 1 or blank (we don't know that from the simplified table). If any other entries are valid, that approach won't be reliable.

Comment: Actually, using ```IF(SUMIFS(...) = 0...``` works if the only possible entries are 1 or blank **AND only 1 cell meets the other criteria**. Nick's comment "sum B8 and C8 cells together" rules that out, so that approach won't be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question*, you can try the following array formula:

```
=LET(letters,B1:E1, letter,"A", data,B3:E13,
 BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,FILTER(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(letters)),letters=letter)),
  LAMBDA(r,IF(OR(r=""),"", SUM(r)))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

The `FILTER` call identifies the column index positions where we have the `A` in the name `letters`. We use `CHOOSECOLS` to select such columns only from `data` (The `A` letter can be on any position of **row 1**). Now we iterate via `BYROW` using as input the output of `CHOOSECOLS`. On each iteration for `r` it checks if there is any blank via `OR` if that is the case, it returns a blank, otherwise the sum of the value in `r`.